# Use CYGWIN to SSH to EC2 Instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin

I am trying to SSH to EC2 from a Windows machine. After installing the CYGWIN (SSH enabled), I tried running the following command:

> ssh -i /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/user/.ssh/user-pc.pem
>   ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Which returns

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

I have also tried changing to directory to /home/user/.ssh and run the command from there after modifying the path to the .pem file accordingly. However, I get the same result.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was reinstalling the Cygwin while making sure that all components of SSH are added during the installation. In addition, I had to 'cd' into the directory with the .pem file and run the command from there.

Comment: why not convert the pem file amazon issues to a putty-compatible key file and just use putty?  or do you need other features that cygwin can provide (X11 forwarding/server ,etc)?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: @ivanivan I am trying to avoid dispersing my attention on different software. if it can be solved with something you already have. For some reason, I never liked PuTTY. Call it a hang-up or something like that but that has been the case.

Answer (score 2):

Try running ssh with the `-t` option, like this:

```
ssh -t -i /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/user/.ssh/user-pc.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

By adding the `-t` option you are telling ssh force the creation of a pseudo-terminal even if it would not normally create one.